# should i change my nodejs document root?

Tags: node.js

Im fairly new to this. Please be kind :D

So this is my folder structure - roughly

```
node
    server.js
webpage
    javascript
    css
       stylesheet.css
    html
       index.html
```

So my server root is the node folder - all the stuff is installe there. I start a server and grab a html file from webpage/html which works fine.

Now in that html file, I cannot seem to link to my CSS because the top folder is node. Whats the best solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! Usually you want to have just one 'top-level' directory that holds all of your code (javascript stuff and your web page stuff). Here's an example project structure:

```
project
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── images
│   └── javascript
├── server.js
└── views
    └── index.html
```

In the example above, `project` would be your main folder, and inside of that you'd have your `server.js`, and then folders for your `assets` (css, javascript, images), and your `views` (html pages).

This is a fairly standard convention.

Comment: I've made this mistake many times :) Sometimes, it is better to hold js+css+images together, separated by modularity, not file extension.